# Barrier Option Pricing using Python

Tags: python, finance, simulation, matplotlib

This is my implementation of pricing an exotic option (in this case an up-and-in barrier option) using the Monte Carlo simulation in Python. I use NumPy where I can. Any ideas to optimize this code?

```
################################################
# Exotic Barrier Option (up-and-in) Pricer 
# By: DudeWah
################################################
#-----------------------------------------------
################################################
# Monte Carlo Simulation pricing an up-and-in  # 
# call option. This call option is a barrier   #
# option in which pyoffs are zero unless the   #
# asset crosses some predifned barrier at some #
# time in [0,T]. If the barrier is crossed,    #
# the payoff becomes that of a European call.  #
# Note: Monte Carlo tends to overestimate the  #
# price of an option. Same fo Barrier Options. #
################################################
#-----------------------------------------------

#import libraries
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
from random import gauss
from math import exp, sqrt

#-----------------------------------------------
#Class for all parameters
#-----------------------------------------------

class parameters():
    """parameters to be used for program"""

    #--------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """initializa parameters"""

        self.S = 5                     #underlying asset price
        self.v = 0.30                  #volatility
        self.r = 0.05                  #10 year risk free rate
        self.T = 365.0/365.0           #years until maturity
        self.K = 6                     #strike price
        self.B = 8                     #barrier price
        self.delta_t = .001            #timestep
        self.N = self.T/self.delta_t   #Number of discrete time points
        self.simulations = 1000        #num of simulations

    #---------------------------
    def print_parameters(self):
        """print parameters"""

        print "---------------------------------------------"
        print "---------------------------------------------"
        print "Pricing an up-and-in option"
        print "---------------------------------------------"
        print "Parameters of Barrier Option Pricer:"
        print "---------------------------------------------"
        print "Underlying Asset Price = ", self.S
        print "Volatility = ", self.v
        print "Risk-Free 10 Year Treasury Rate =", self.r
        print "Years Until Expiration = ", self.T
        print "Time-Step = ", self.delta_t
        print "Discrete time points =", self.N
        print "Number of Simulations = ", self.simulations
        print "---------------------------------------------"
        print "---------------------------------------------"


#-----------------------------------------------
#Class for Monte Carlo
#-----------------------------------------------    

class up_and_in_mc(parameters):
    """This is the class to price the barrier option 
       defined as an up and in option. Paramaters are
       fed in as a subclass"""

    #---------------------------   
    def __init__(self):
        """initialize the class including the subclass"""
        parameters.__init__(self)
        self.payoffs = []
        self.price_trajectories = []
        self.discount_factor = exp(-self.r * self.T)


    #---------------------------
    def call_payoff(self,s):
        """use to price a call"""
        self.cp = max(s - self.K, 0.0)
        return self.cp



    #---------------------------
    def calculate_payoff_vector(self):
        """Main iterative loop to run the 
        Monte Carlo simulation. Returns a vector
        of different potential payoffs"""

        for i in xrange(0, self.simulations):
            self.stock_path = []
            self.S_j = self.S
            for j in xrange(0, int(self.N-1)):
                self.xi = gauss(0,1.0)

                self.S_j *= (exp((self.r-.5*self.v*self.v) * self.delta_t + self.v *sqrt(self.delta_t) * self.xi))

                self.stock_path.append(self.S_j)
            self.price_trajectories.append(self.stock_path)
            if max(self.stock_path) > self.B:
                self.payoffs.append(self.call_payoff(self.stock_path[-1]))
            elif max(self.stock_path) < self.B:
                self.payoffs.append(0)

        return self.payoffs           

    #---------------------------
    def compute_price(self):
        """Uses payoff vector and discount
        factor to compute the price of the
        option. Numpy used for efficiency"""
        self.np_payoffs = np.array(self.payoffs, dtype=float) 
        self.np_Vi = self.discount_factor*self.np_payoffs 
        self.price = np.average(self.np_Vi)

    #---------------------------
    def print_price(self):
        """prints the option price to terminal"""
        print str("Call Price: %.4f") % self.price
        print "---------------------------------------------"

    #---------------------------
    def calc_statistics(self):
        """uses payoffs and price to calc
        variance, standard deviation, and
        a 95% confidence interval for price"""
        self.variance = np.var(self.np_Vi)
        self.sd = np.std(self.np_Vi)
        #95% C.I. uses 1.96 z-value
        self.CI = [self.price - (1.96*self.sd/sqrt(float(self.simulations))),
                   self.price + (1.96*self.sd/sqrt(float(self.simulations)))]

    #---------------------------
    def print_statistics(self):
        """prints option statistics that were
        calculated to the terminal"""
        print "Variance: %.4f" % self.variance
        print "Standard Deviation: %.4f" % self.sd
        print "95% Confidence Interval:", self.CI
        print "---------------------------------------------"
        print "---------------------------------------------\n"

    #---------------------------
    def plot_trajectories(self):
    """uses matplotlib to plot the trajectory
    of each individual stock stored in earlier
    trajectory array"""
    print "Creating Plot..."
    #use numpy to plot 
    self.np_price_trajectories = np.array(self.price_trajectories, dtype=float)
    self.times = np.linspace(0, self.T, self.N-1)

    #style/plot/barrier line
    style.use('dark_background')

    self.fig = plt.figure()
    self.ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((1,1),(0,0))
    for sublist in self.np_price_trajectories:
        if max(sublist) > self.B:
            self.ax1.plot(self.times,sublist,color = 'cyan')
        else:
            self.ax1.plot(self.times,sublist,color = '#e2fb86')
    plt.axhline(y=8,xmin=0,xmax=self.T,linewidth=2, color = 'red', label = 'Barrier')

    #rotate and add grid
    for label in self.ax1.xaxis.get_ticklabels():
        label.set_rotation(45)
    self.ax1.grid(True)

    #plotting stuff
    plt.xticks(np.arange(0, self.T+self.delta_t, .1))
    plt.suptitle('Stock Price Trajectory', fontsize=40)
    plt.legend()
    self.leg = plt.legend(loc= 2)
    self.leg.get_frame().set_alpha(0.4)
    plt.xlabel('Time (in years)', fontsize = 30)
    plt.ylabel('Price', fontsize= 30)
    plt.show()

#-----------------------------------------------
#Main Program
#-----------------------------------------------

#Initialize and print parameters
prm = parameters()
prm.print_parameters()

#Price/print the option
ui_mc = up_and_in_mc()
ui_mc.calculate_payoff_vector()
ui_mc.compute_price()
ui_mc.print_price()

#caclulate/print stats
ui_mc.calc_statistics()
ui_mc.print_statistics()

#plot
ui_mc.plot_trajectories()
```

Comment: when the line crosses the barrier do you want the whole line to change colour or just the part that crossed the barrier

Comment: I believe I figured that out. Updated the OP to reflect this. I can't seem to plot the legend properly though. My barrier is plotting fine on the legend, but because my actual plot is in a for loop, I can't seem to keep my legend to only one output per color. I don't know if there is a way to make a legend from scratch, but I think that's necessary here.